# CakePHP3 ~ CSRF-token mismatch on second function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-3.0

I am currently developing an JavaScript reliable system that works with the CakePHP 3 framework as the back-end. All the actions in my panel are executed on the same page / url, it is a one-page-application. Currently I got a bunch of functions working and decided it was time to investigate the CSRF-component of CakePHP 3. When I enabled it I got the 400 error which indicated that no CSRF-token was given. After a lot of research I came to the solution that this is fixed with the FormMaker or with manually implementing the token in my JQuery ajax request. This worked so I decided to also implement it the next function. But as you may guess, this did not work. The second ajax request gives a CSRF-token mismatch. Please look at my code below:

My first request that actually works:

```
function getSectionData(controller, method = null) {
    fetch("<?=$this->Url->build(['controller' => '']);?>" + "/" + controller + "/getSectionData", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRF-Token": <?= json_encode($this->request->param('_csrfToken')); ?>
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                method: method
            })
        })
            .then((res) =>
                res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.warn(data);
                let response = data.response;

                if (response.success == 1) {
                    // Action to do when data has been received
                    let method = response.method;
                    let rows = response.rows;

                    window[method](controller, rows);
                } else if (response.success == 0) {
                    // Message when an error occures

                }

            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Eventually the second function gets activated after less than a second:

```
function renderElement(element, id, data = null) {
    let path = "<?= $this->request->here; ?>" + "/renderElement/" + element;
    $('#' + id).load(path, {
        data: data, 
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-Token": <?= json_encode($this->request->param('_csrfToken')); ?>
        }
    });
}
```

In this function I load a preset HTML element from another file which can contain data-elements, that is why it first requests data from the controller. I use the same headers as in the first function and the CSRF-token is present in the console. But it does not work and throws the mismatch error. I would like to know why it gives this error and how I can solve it, like, do I have to refresh it and how?

Note that I am using a version of CakePHP 3 before the 3.6 update which removed the CSRF component and added the CRSF middleware.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery.load()` function doesn't accept AJAX configuration parameters, the second argument is either a callback, or an object that defines the POST data to submit alongside the request.

You'll either have to switch to using a configurable AJAX request (for example as in your first snippet), or globally configure jQuery to set the required header for all AJAX requests:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': <?= json_encode($this->request->param('_csrfToken')); ?>
    }
});
```

See also

- **https://api.jquery.com/load/**
- **https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/**

Comment: I used the ajaxSetup as suggested and it worked. Thanks a lot! I was wondering if there is a standard location to do this. Right now I pasted it at the beginning of my script, but I don't know if this is the ideal location.

Comment: @TomDijkema In a one page application it probably doesn't really matter too much, as long as it's placed so that it runs before any AJAX request is being issued.